# SVN options not coming in Eclipse Springsource

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

For Eclipse Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.5.1,

Have installed Subclipse 1.10 and other plugins like Subversion Client Adapter.
Still, on right clicking a file and under menu 'Team', SVN options are not coming up.

Thanks in advance, Kakoli

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to reinstall the plugin http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA and restart eclipse.